What assumptions can I make about the y values of the parabolas in Simpson's rule?
For some background, I'm creating a small educational program to help students visualize common numerical integration methods. I've run into a slight problem however. When creating an animation approximating a function using Simpson's rule the y axis jump around because unlike Riemann sums, and the trapezoid method, the parabolas used to calculate sums can have their ranges extend outside the range of the function being calculated. Here's a visualization of this happening in action:

My question is if it's possible, given a function and a number of partitions, to calculate the max and minimum values of the set parabola's used to create the approximation of the area under the function. With these values, I can just set the y-axis range and not worry about the axis jumping around.
I realize I can also just calculate the max and minimum y values after calculating each parabola, but I was wondering if it was possible to get the values with just the function and number of partitions.
Thanks!

Honestly I sort of like that it jumps around since it demonstrates visually that the approximation can go outside the range of the function. It's almost an easter egg.

Frankly, with your "small educational program to help students visualize common numerical integration methods" you offer a tool to compare different approaches. If now Simpson's rule turns out as inapt or problematic in some cases, your tool has succeed me think.
